# Accessing class that already filled up by another class IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have problem about accessing class, and i ve been looking for solution, couldnt figured out yet.

I have 3 classes: 
1 - ViewController 
2 - XmlParser 
3 - AllDeals,

When i open app, ViewController uses XmlParses class, and XmlParser class parses xml file and stores information into `NSMutableArray` in the `XmlParser` Class.

I would like to access that `NSMutableArray`(in XmlParser class) and all information that it stored already from AllDeals class. I cannot split up Xml file again. it s taking too much time.
When i tried to access nothing comes. I have tried many things.
How am i gonna point or access that class or `NSMutableArray`... 
Thank you for your helps.

Comment: what do you mean with filled up?

Comment: i mean i parsed xml file and the data stored in the NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use shared instance of XmlParser Class ? If Not then make shared instance whenever you want to use this class and access that NSMutableArray with the help of XmlParser Class shared instance.

Comment: Wow shared instance solved my problem. Awesome, THank you very much. :) i was gonna be crazy...

Answer (score 0):

if you're aware about the delegates then you can pass values over delegate at the success of your parsing else create one NSMutableArray into your 1-ViewController globally and take advantage of it by passing the parent of viewController to XmlParser then you'll have filled NSMutableArray of your desired output and access it further more.